# Aurelia bindable e plugins jQuery

Tags: jquery

Estou com um problema com as variáveis bindable e plugins jQuery que manipulam o valor de inputs. Testei o seguinte código e constatei que o Aurelia não escuta as alterações de valores feita por `$.fn.val`:

```
<template>
  <input id="my-input" value.bind="inputvalue" type="text">
</template>
```

---

```
class MyClass {
  @bindable inputvalue;

  constructor() {
    this.inputvalue = 'First value'
  }

  bind() {
    setTimeout(() => {
      $('#my-input').val('Some value').change();
      // No input o valor é 'Some value',
      // mas na variável bindable this.inputvalue o valor ainda é 'First value'
    }, 4000);
  }
}
```

Tem alguma maneira de resolver esse problema?

Answer (score 1):

#### Primeiro, o ideal:

Como o *binding* está conectando objetos do Aurelia (ou seja, View e ViewModel), o ideal seria você não usar um agente externo (jQuery, neste caso) para atualizar sua View diretamente. Isso fará com que a alteração não seja rastreada e, consequentemente, ocorra a dessincronização mencionada.

Solução:

```
bind() {
  setTimeout(() => {
    // setar o valor diretamente em sua VM, que então atualizará a View, 
    // considerando que o bind padrão para inputs é de duas vias (two-way)
    this.inputvalue = 'Some value';     
  }, 4000);
}
```

#### Agora, o *workaround*:

Se a situação na realidade é mais complexa e realmente tiver que forçar o refresh do binding manualmente, é necessário [sinalizar esta ação](https://www.danyow.net/aurelia-binding-behaviors/#signal).

Para isso:

1) Em sua **View**, adicionar o binding behavior do tipo `signal` ao(s) binding(s) desejado(s):

```
<template>
  <input id="my-input" value.bind="inputvalue & signal:'forcar-refresh'" type="text">
</template>
```

2) Em sua **ViewModel**, sinalizar a mudança notificando todos os bindings inscritos a se atualizarem:

```
import {BindingSignaler} from 'aurelia-templating-resources';

@inject(BindingSignaler)
class MyClass {
  @bindable inputvalue;
  signaler;

  constructor(signaler) {
    this.inputvalue = 'First value';
    this.signaler = signaler;
  }

  bind() {
    setTimeout(() => {
      $('#my-input').val('Some value').change();
      this.signaler.signal('forcar-refresh'); // <--- Aqui
    }, 4000);
  }
}
```

Comment: Eu consegui resolver o problema, acho que usando o `value.two-way` se não me engano. [Essa resposta no SOen me ajudou](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40050162/3497987). Mas quando tiver um tempinho vou testar a tua resposta.

Comment: Legal @KaduAmaral. Se você conseguir recuperar tua solução e verificar que ela é mais fácil de implementar, creio que valeria postar ela aqui e marcar como a resposta.

Comment: Sim vou fazer isso quando tiver um tempinho... Valeu pela resposta. :)